# what is the most efficient way to move a column in a dataframe

Tags: r

I want to move a column on the right to some place on the left of the data frame. Since I am moving only one column and I have many columns. I think reordering like this  df <- df[,c("a","b","d","c")] won't be efficient. Since the dataframe contains many rows, I want to minimize rewriting things

from:

```
 name var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 ... varN
 a     1    1    1    1    1        1
 b     1    1    1    1    1        1
 c     1    1    1    1    1        1
```

to:

```
  name var1 varN var2 var3 var4 ... varN-1
   a     1    1    1    1    1        1
   b     1    1    1    1    1        1
   c     1    1    1    1    1        1
```

Comment: Look into `dplyr`'s `select` function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a vector of column indices rather than a vector of column names, so you can take advantage of sequence notation, like so:

```
my_seq = c(1,ncol(df),2:(ncol(df)-1))
df[,my_seq]
```

For example, if your dataframe has 17 columns, we get:

```
> my_seq
 [1]  1 17  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get there with `append`:

```
df <- data.frame(name=letters[1:5],var1=1,var2=1,var3=1,var4=1,var5=1)

# using names
df[append(names(df)[-ncol(df)], names(df)[ncol(df)], after=2)]

# using positions
df[append(seq(ncol(df)-1), ncol(df), after=2)]

#  name var1 var5 var2 var3 var4
#1    a    1    1    1    1    1
#2    b    1    1    1    1    1
#3    c    1    1    1    1    1
#4    d    1    1    1    1    1
#5    e    1    1    1    1    1
```

Comment: would you recommend that as a solution, given how clunky the code is? Base R allows for the numerical indexing, which seems more intuitive than your suggestion. When would this be the preferred approach?

Comment: @brittenb - the second example I give above is numerical indexing. It's no clunkier than `df[, c(1, ncol(df), 2:(ncol(df)-1))]`

Comment: I don't like including the `ncol` function in the indexing either; I agree that it's clunky. I'd just set it up as two lines: `N <- ncol(df); df <- df[, c(1, N, 2:(N-1))]` I just think the append and seq convolute what's going on. Just my two cents though. I was only asking because ive seen your other answers and know you know what you're talking about, so I was looking for your reasoning.

Comment: @brittenb - I see how the indexing could be considered simpler. I do like having the formal `after=2` argument. Just a preference issue I suppose.

Comment: My `moveMe` function is basically a fancy and flexible implementation of using `append`.... +1

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend looking at [the `moveMe` function](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun/blob/master/R/moveMe.R) from [my "SOfun" package](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun).

With it, the solution would be something like:

```
df <- data.frame(name=letters[1:5],var1=1,var2=1,var3=1,var4=1,var5=1)

library(SOfun)

df[moveMe(names(df), "var5 before var4")]
#   name var1 var2 var3 var5 var4
# 1    a    1    1    1    1    1
# 2    b    1    1    1    1    1
# 3    c    1    1    1    1    1
# 4    d    1    1    1    1    1
# 5    e    1    1    1    1    1
```

You can also compound statements:

```
df[moveMe(names(df), "var5 before var2; name last")]
#   var1 var5 var2 var3 var4 name
# 1    1    1    1    1    1    a
# 2    1    1    1    1    1    b
# 3    1    1    1    1    1    c
# 4    1    1    1    1    1    d
# 5    1    1    1    1    1    e
```

---

If you want to do this most efficiently, you should consider converting your data to a "data.table", and using `setcolorder`. This would change the column order by reference, and not by making copies of your data.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)

setcolorder(dt, moveMe(names(dt), "var5 before var4"))
dt
#    name var1 var2 var3 var5 var4
# 1:    a    1    1    1    1    1
# 2:    b    1    1    1    1    1
# 3:    c    1    1    1    1    1
# 4:    d    1    1    1    1    1
# 5:    e    1    1    1    1    1
```

Answer (score 0):

with `dplyr`

```
df %>% select(name,var1,varN,everthing())
```

Comment: He isn't asking to delete a column. He wants to move the last column to the left.

Answer (score 0):

If data frame `df` has `n` columns and you have to move `m`th column to 2nd position from start

`df <- subset(df, select=c(1, m, 2:m-1, m+1:n))`

In your case:

`df <- subset(df, select=c(name:var1, varN, var2:varN-1))`

It can also be written as :

`df <- subset(df, select=c(name, var1, varN, var2, var3,....,varN-1))`

You can use columns names as well as column numbers for passing the new order of columns.